# How can I connect a Syquest EZ135 drive to a modern computer?

Tags: hard-drive, connection

The drive and disks are over 10 yrs old so I have little hope, but what kind of cable could I use to make this drive readable on a modern PC (Vista)?

Is there an adaptor that has to be used?

For reference, this site has a lot of info on [ez135 drives](http://siber-sonic.com/mac/Vintage/EZ135.html).

[image: ports on ez135]

Comment: That's a Centronics cable, not a SCSI cable.

Comment: Nope 'tis 50 way SCSI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Centronics_50_SCSI_connector.JPG

Comment: @Linker3000: The page said "printer".

Comment: That's not a printer interface - I can even see the SCSI ID selector - set to 5 (top of pic) - or are we talking at crossed purposes??

Comment: Centronics is the *connector* type, the cable is SCSI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have one of these...and it works...

you need a centronics-50 to db25 scsi cable, a centronics 50 type terminator, and a scsi card that it will connect to like an adaptec ava2902e.

You MUST have the drive plugged in and turned on when booting or you won't be able to mount the filesystem.

Comment: Where can you get this cable?

Answer (score 1):

It's a SCSI peripheral (SCSI 1). One connector to the computer, one for an SCSI terminator or other SCSI peripherals in a chain. This device needs an SCSI adapter in your computer, some types are possible...

Answer (score 1):

That connector is definitely SCSI. I used that same model with several Amiga computers, and it's a SCSI-2 connector.

Also, it's not terminated internally. If you don't connect anything else to the other SCSI-2 connector, you have to put a terminator on the other one, otherwise it'll lock up the system--or at least it will on an Amiga, but I'm sure it won't behave nicely on other computers if you don't terminate it either...

Answer (score 0):

A USB-(or PATA-, SATA-, etc.)to-SCSI adapter should work fine, but make sure that it really *is* a SCSI adapter and not, in fact, a printer adapter.

Comment: Looks like you are correct. It isn't SCSI.

Comment: But it doesn't look like Centronics either.  When I look at centronics cables it shows about 20 metal contacts.  This drive has 25 metal contacts across.

Comment: Since it has two connectors, I'd go with 50-way SCSI - one for the data link to the PC and one for a daisychain/terminator connector, although the drive may be terminated internally - I'd take the cover off and have a look at the drive interface, that should settle it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this device [Syquest ez135] with all the paper work & install disks. It uses a parallel printer port. Unfortunately it also uses win95 & so far I have not found a way to get WinXP to see the drive.  So you have two issues, you need a parallel printer port and a modern driver.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. We're a Q&A community, not a conventional forum, so answer posts must answer (or attempt to answer) the question—answer posts which fail to do so are subject to deletion.